# D difference between z-index's auto and inherited in CSS3

Tags: css

I am gong through the z-index property of CSS3 and it has got four properties , auto , number , inline and inherit. I understand number and inline but auto and inherit confuse me as auto mean "sets the value as parent's value as it's default value" and inherit means "inherits the value from parent". I googled but didn't really understand it.

Comment: Where did you read that `z-index` can be `inline`?. It only has `auto | <integer> | inherit` [w3c: CSS/Properties/z-index](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/z-index)

Comment: Edited : i understand inherit but as auto is the default value  ? what is the default value ? is it 0? Does it mean providing a z-index : auto and not providing any value are same ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`z-index` is not inherited; the default value for every element is `auto`. If you change it to be `inherit` then it will grab the value from its parent directly.

The key is that `auto` does not create a new local stacking context, while `inherit`, if the parent had any numerical value, will indeed.

Please check this example to get a better understanding. You can see the same DOM structure is duplicated. On the first scenario, div `auto` comes before `inherit` and on the other one; it's inverted.

You can see that the `inherit` value works equally as actually setting `z-index: <number>` equal to the parent, while `auto` is the default value that does not create a new stacking order and will simply display on the default z order as per determinated on the DOM. If you make the parent's value -1, then the inheritance will be exactly as if you set `z-index: -1` on `.inherit` making it display behind `.auto` on both divs.

```js
$('#button0').click(function(e){
  $('.parent').css('z-index', '0');
});
$('#button1').click(function(e){
  $('.parent').css('z-index', '1');
});
$('#button-1').click(function(e){
  $('.parent').css('z-index', '-1');
});
```

```css
.parent{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.parent > div{
  position: absolute;
}
.auto{
  z-index: auto; /* default value */
}
.inherit{
  z-index: inherit;  
}

/* --------------------- */
/* presentational styles */
.auto{
  background: green;
}
.inherit{
  top: 100px;
  background: red;
}
.parent{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  opacity: 1;
  margin: 10px;
  background: yellow;
  display: inline-block;
}
.parent > div{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  opacity: 0.95;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  first auto and then inherit on DOM
  <div class="auto">auto</div>
  <div class="inherit">inherit</div>
</div>

<div class="parent">
  first inherit and then auto on DOM
  <div class="inherit">inherit</div>
  <div class="auto">auto</div>
</div>

<div>
  <label>Change z-index of parent</label>
  <button id="button-1">To -1</button>
  <button id="button0">To 0</button>
  <button id="button1">To 1</button>
</div>
```

More information on MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Comment: i understand inherit but as auto is the default value  ? what is the default value ? is it 0?

Comment: `auto` and `0` are the same in this scenario, yes. In essence it means not to go behind or on top of its siblings, and the stacking is determinated by the way elements are introduced on the DOM. However, `auto` does not generate a new local stacking context, while `0`, as per the definition of integer value, will (this would affect children elements)

Comment: Ok.. so auto so auto means how the normal elements are placed on the DOM as z-idex values 0 and without any stacking context ?

Answer (score 0):

If an element 'a' is child of element 'b', then element 'b' is called the parent.If z-index of element 'b' is 5.0 and z-index of element 'a' is set to inherit, element 'a' will also have z-index 5.0.That's what inheritance means.